# How to prevent documents from being stolen via Linux live CD

Tags: linux, documents

I have a PC with Windows installed on it (like most people), and I can retrieve data from it using a Linux Live CD if need be. However, it dawns on me that anybody could simply steal any information/data/documents off of my PC by using this same method, as the information is actually stored on one of the drives, and therefore accessible. I have already retrieved data in the past off of my PC when it BSOD, but it hadn't occurred to me then that anyone could grab my documents for themselves.

Would there be a way for me to prevent this from happening? After all, my data isn't actually secure, despite my PC being password protected under normal circumstances.

Comment: Your Windows password is pretty worthless anyway so encryption is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is disk encryption. Enabling disk encryption will scramble the contents of the drive in a way such that only someone who possesses the encryption key can unscramble it and read the contents.

Fortunately, most modern operating systems have disk encryption features built in. If you have a Pro edition of Windows, you likely already have access to Bitlocker which is Microsoft's disk encryption tool. Just go to My Computer, right click your drive, and click "Turn on Bitlocker."

If you only have a Home edition of Windows and don't have access to Bitlocker, there are free and paid third-party tools you can use instead. [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) comes to mind as one of the most reputable free solutions.

Comment: Thanks. That's so true. Bitlocker is so out of the way for the most part lol, that I hadn't even thought of it. I used it once (years ago), but never thought of using it for this specific purpose. Thanks!


Also, I will keep Veracrypt in mind in case I need a free solution :)

Comment: @user54600 you may want to look into veracrypt anyway, it has a lot of other useful features, such as protecting drives and containers with a hidden volume that uses a second password, so even if you're forced to reveal a password, you can keep things safe. secondly it also allows the creation of containers. Something bitlocker does not do. So in the event you are on the system and run some sort of malware where the disk encryption is at that point useless the files are still safe in containers.

Comment: @Nalaurien, thanks for that piece of information. I will look at it for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at some Anti-Virus software they can offer a secured "Vault as they call it. I know BitDefender definitely offers this options. And that essentially just takes a predefined amount of space and encrypts it requiring the software and a password to access it later.

Comment: That's cool. I know that Bitdefender is said to be a pretty good piece of software, but it doesn't agree with my PC - at any time I've had a fresh copy of Windows 7. It either freezes or BSODS, so I've given up on ever using Bitdefender. I've even had to switch my Comodo Firewall a few months back, since it seems that that Comodo has gone for Windows 10 support more than 7 :/

Comment: Yeah I can imagine being on Windows 7 these days is pretty hard, but if you do upgrade I would definitely recommended BitDefender. Its packed full a great features like getting notification on a smart phone when a threat is detected.

Comment: It's pretty good for the most part. I mean, I actually use older accessories which are fully compatible with it, so it's not much of an issue. The worst is when a company thinks they should fade out support for Windows 7. I am honestly wondering if I should switch to Windows 10 (I smell yearly subscription based ideas floating in the air) and obtain, as you were proposing, Bitdefender, or if I should switch to Linux. Although Linux is a pain to get anything to run in a similar fashion as a Windows based operating system.

Comment: I run both Windows and Linux and after playing around and finding the right Linux for you it’s actually a pretty great experience. And you can run some Windows application through it using a program called Wine. I think the open source OS are the way ahead as they offer a much greater sense of control

Comment: I actually had both installed at some point, and had wine. Never got around to using it though, since I had Windows 7 in a dual boot. I have heard it's a prettfy nifty piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to turn off booting CD or USB in BIOS and then enabling BIOS password.

Comment: But, wouldn't this prevent me from accessing my own PC if I need to recover the information using my Linux CD? I mean, assuming I do not remove the password beforehand.

Comment: but still you know the password right. You can enter BIOS anytime and change the setting to re enable boot from CD. Once you are done you can disable it back.

Comment: Makes 100% sense. I guess I had misunderstood what I read the first time around, although I fully understand now by re-reading it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disk crypto doesn't prevent evil maid attack though. Get some clear resin/binary epoxy, mix copper filings into it. Then apply it to the screws on the disk, and on the PC cabinet. Take pictures of that. The arrangement of filings in the hardened resin || epoxy are nigh impossible to duplicate.

Then set a bios boot password. And a bios master password. Now nobody can remove the disk to implant an evil maid variant - without making you aware that it has been removed.

Bitdefender is likely crippled by microsoft to provide law enforcement access, assume the same for Filevault. If this is relevant, use Veracrypt. Since you don't say which country you're in, you may have legitimate reasons for wanting to use VeraCrypt.

If you are gung-ho on DIY tamperproof, periodically check the glue splotches against your pictures.

Now you got to do the same with your keyboard to prevent logging implant in its case (they're dirt cheap with arduino micro). 
Well, maybe not necessary - but an attacker doesn't need to make it, he can buy it cheaply. The point is that you need perimeter security. Not some dirty old Kwikset lock either, a real nice lock with laser-cut sidebar.

Comment: Hmm, as a now old dinausaur, I always try to measure to gain/cost ratio of security actions, what risk they mitigate, and what is the actual risk **I** want to mitigate. If an evil guy can have access to my home computer, I will not care much for possible stealth of files but more for stealth of the whole computer or other values in my house... What is the threat, and only then what is the appropriate counter measure. Of course, there are real use cases for the security measures you describe, but they are not that common.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sure, it's somewhat a rhetorical answer. Some journalists do this to detect malware implants when taking their laptops through customs, though. For a PC to prevent being stolen, make it unsellable.